# How do I add a string at the end of user input in SQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a SQL query that is based on user input.
However, in the table, theres a "-1" at the end of every word that you search for.
For example if you want to get the sql result of car, it's actually named car-1 in the database, but the user should only be able to search for car.
This is how its setup:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM that WHERE this = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$search_query = $_POST['this'];
$stmt->bind_param('s', $search_query);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

What I want, is that the select query should be like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM that WHERE this = ? + '-1'";
```

But ^^ doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE NAME='car' & -1";

test = that
NAME= table name
'car' = this
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just concat `-1` to `search_query` :

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM that WHERE this = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$search_query = $_POST['this'];
$stmt->bind_param('s', $search_query.'-1');
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using MySQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM that WHERE this = CONCAT(?, '-1')";
```

Using PHP:

```
$stmt->bind_param('s', $search_query . "-1");
```